# Mapping of bundle names onto respective directory path in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm not sure how to put that question. It's a bit fuzzy, but if you encountered the Corpus Delicti, you'll know what I mean.

When I first came across how Symfony2 maps bundles onto paths, few days ago, I already felt bit puzzled about why they chose to map a Bundle name of

`AxxBxxBundle` onto `.../Axx/BxxBundle/...`

To me this decision seems arbitrary and confusing, don't get me wrong this is not a serious obstacle and you get used to it within five minutes, but still I think it smells funny.

Now I just came across this quote in the [Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html):

> BundleName:ControllerName:TemplateName
>
> This is the logical name of the template, which is mapped to a
>   physical location using the following convention.
>
> /path/to/BundleName/Resources/views/ControllerName/TemplateName

And this is wrong I think, there would have to be slash between Bundle and Name.

But this quote shows me that even in the inner Symfony2 circle some people don't find that intuitive.

So what is the "philosophy" bind this bundle thing and its mapping logic?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html) doesn't exactly answer the question about the reasoning, but it provides some more information on the `Bundle`-topic. To get an answer on the **why**, you should perhaps contact [Fabien Potencier](https://twitter.com/#!/fabpot) who wrote the [`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php) class which relies on this convention.

Comment: I will contact him; do you have his number by any chance? :D

Comment: I wouldn't post it here - if I had it ;-)

Comment: Your devotedness to morale and duty makes my heart almost melt!

Answer (score 2):

Coming from Zend Framework, it's not that bad for me. All those classes start with Zend_ Thinking of it as the owner/creater's name makes it easier. In java most libraries start with com.foobar

Quoting Fabien: "Symfony2 relies on well-know design patterns, and best practices coming from the Java world."

Your statement does not really make sense or I'm missing your point:

> And this is wrong I think, there would have to be slash between Bundle
>   and Name.

Did you mean: Between Acme and DemoBundle? It does feel like a duplication, but

Quoting Fabien: "A bundle is a structured set of files that implements a single feature and can be easily shared with other developers."

I can use a blog bundle from Acme, then I find a similar bundle from Emca. Most likely their bundles will have the same model&controller&route names. Using them both: this way nothing gets overridden using another library. So the first name for the creator/owner is to prevent duplication.

Since it's a pain to use, I always call mine **My**/DemoBundle for quicker use :p Or you can give it a custom name during the console bundle generation (if you don't like it)

Also:

> All core bundles are treated the exact same as your bundles and
>   everything is a bundle. Bundles are easily portable and configurable.
>   They are really the key to Symfony2’s real power. A bundle can extend
>   another bundle. It can be distributed independently from it’s
>   application.

Since the web assets are in the bundle, I believe they managed to get it right. That will allow easy configuration and reusability, e.g. bigger (scope) improvements can be made to the symfony core without effecting your app.